# How to not display non-printable caracters with wget output?

Tags: bash, wget

I'm making a bash script to retrieve some html content, the command line is:

```
wget http://some_url.com -q -O -output.txt -o /dev/null
```

But when there are images in the page wget still "display" those with non-printable caracters.

Is there a way to tell to wget to not display those non-printable caracters ?

Cheers

p.s: as a matter of fact, i can't do any grep on the "output.txt" as it is considered as a binary file (because of the non printable caracters)

You can try with thsi url for instance: https://www.offensive-security.com/pwbonline/icq.html

Comment: Without knowing the url you are requesting it could be anything. You might be downloading an image for all anyone here knows.

Comment: @123 i just edited my post

Comment: the page is ssl. Use the `--secure-protocol=protocol` flag. It can be any of these `auto`, `SSLv2`,`SSLv3`,`TLSv1`.

Comment: @123 i've tried every of the options you suggested but non printables caracteres still appears

Answer (score 0):

Usually HTML documents won't contain binary data. I can't reproduce this specific problem.

If it is just about to force `grep` to search in files which would usually being skipped because `grep` assumes they are binary, use `--binary-files=text`:

```
wget -O- http://server.com/url | grep --binary-files=text 'foo.*bar'
```

Comment: actually i don't know if it's binary, because i created the file as a .txt, but when i do grep on it i get this message: "corresponding binary file", also i using the option you suggest doesn't help. I think the only way for me would be to remove all the non printables caracters from the file but i don't know how